# Standard for Chemistry Supplies

Tags: equipment

In searching for chemistry kits it often leads to stuff like [this](https://www.homesciencetools.com/product/abeka-chemistry-lab-kit/):

[image]

I have seen some nicer "boxed sets" for the ~$500 range, but I don't think this is really ideal. [This one](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1742632993/heirloom-chemistry-set) looks a little nicer. I am wondering two things:

1. Where the best "complete" home/DIY chemistry set is that you can get online. Including the chemicals themselves, and the equipment like beakers, pipettes, etc.
2. Where the standard places are that smaller or bigger labs like University student or research labs get their supplies.

I feel like I read somewhere a while back that it is being outlawed because of bad behavior, but I wanted to ask to see what is possible in terms of doing chemistry experiments/analysis in a DIY/bootstrap fashion to learn about things like way in the past. I don't know much about chemistry but it would be interesting to perhaps learn how to do analysis like you might (I imagine) find in biology, geoscience, ecology, or agriculture.

Comment: >Where the best "complete" home/DIY chemistry set is that you can get online || There is no universal one. Once you decide on specific DIY branch, you should buy a separate set of chemicals and glassware, most of which are reasonably easily accessible. Furthermore, the exact choice of the chemicals and glassware might change with available setup.

Comment: This is a bit too opinion based for main site Q&A but perhaps you could ask for input in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on question 2.

As a former chemistry student, I saw that most chemicals were ordered at:

- Sigma Aldrich
- Biosolve
- Fisher Scientific
- ThermoFisher Scientific
- Local pharmacy (at least in Holland)

Equipment was often ordered directly at the manufacturer (like an HPLC) unless the device is pretty general, like a rotary evaporator.

Comment: most of the chemical suppliers refuse to sell to consumers.

Comment: @A.K. Depending on country, purchasing chemicals can be highly regulated. The location of OP and whether he has the money or knowledge to run actual lab is not clear.